# Grails 2.5: how to propogate the IP address down to service layer?

Tags: grails

The controller layer can get the IP using `request.getRemoteAddr()` and/or `request.getHeader("Client-IP")` etc.

However, down in the bowels of the service layer, we might want to log some detected or suspected fraudulent activity by the user, along with the IP address of the user. However, the IP is not available to the service layer, nor is the request.

Obviously, every call from every controller method to every single service method could also pass in the IP or the request, but as we have thousands of these calls and lots of chains of them, it is not really practical.

Can anyone think of a better way?

As we are not in charge of instantiation of the services (these just get magically injected), we can't even pass the IP in when each service is created for the current HTTP call.

### UPDATE 1

As suggested, tried the MDC route. Unfortunately, this does not seem to work.

in filter:

```
import org.apache.log4j.MDC
class IpFilters  {

def filters = {

    all() {
        before = {
            MDC.put "IP", "1.1.1.1"
            println "MDC.put:" + MDC.get("IP")
        }
        afterView = { Exception e ->
            println "MDC.remove:" + MDC.get("IP")
            MDC.remove 'IP'
        }
}
```

in service:

```
import org.apache.log4j.MDC
:
def someMethod() {
    String ip = MDC.get("IP")
    println("someMethod: IP = $ip")
}
```

The result is always:

```
MDC.put:1.1.1.1
MDC.remove:1.1.1.1
someMethod: IP = null
```

So the service cant access MDC variables put on the thread in the filter, which is a real shame.  Possibly the problem is that "someMethod" is actually called by springSecuirty.

Comment: I'd recommend you investigate using MDC logging. You could, easily, setup a filter that adds/removes this information before/after each request. Given the nature of MDC it would be available via ThreadLocal and thus any layer for the current thread. http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/effective-logging-in-javajee-mapped-diagnostic-context.html

Comment: You could also think of doing this using AOP and probably write a before interceptor where you could do your logging. Something like this: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/integrating-of-spring-aop-with-grails-application/

Comment: I dont think AOP is applicable here - we dont want to log entry to a particular method - there is logic inside the method which decides if something needs to be written or not (e.g. when authenticating a user, if they got the password wrong).  Also, the same problem exists, how does the AOP get access to the request IP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is highly recommended that we should keep the business logic aware of the controller logic. But keeping your situation in mind, you have to do that and absolutely available. In your service method, write this to log the IP address of the **current request**:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

// ... your code and class

def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest()
println request.getRemoteAddr()
```

Just make sure, you handle the whatever exception thrown from that line when the same service method is invoked from outside a Grails request context like from a Job.

Answer (score 0):

my two pence worth

basically been using above and it works perfectly fine when a request is directed through standard grails practices.

In this scenario, user triggers websockets connection this then is injected into websockets listener using Holders.applicationContext.

The issue arises around are your outside of the web request.

the fix was painful but may come in handy for anyone else in this situation:

```
private static String userIp

 String getIp() {
        String i
        new Thread({
            //to bypass :
            // Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a
            // request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request
            // and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet:
            // In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
            def webRequest = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()
            if(!webRequest) {
                def servletContext  = ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()
                def applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
                webRequest =  grails.util.GrailsWebMockUtil.bindMockWebRequest(applicationContext)
            }
        //def request = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().request
            def request = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().currentRequest
            i=request.getRemoteAddr()
            if (!i ||i == '127.0.0.1') {
                i=request.getHeader("X-Forwarded-For")
            }
            if (!i ||i == '127.0.0.1') {
                i=request.getHeader("Client-IP")
            }
            if (!i) { i="127.0.0.1"}
            this.userIp=i
        } as Runnable ).start()

        return i
    }
```

Now when calling this some sleep time is required due to it running in as a runnable :

```
 def aa = getIp()
        sleep(300)
        println "$aa is aa"
        println "---- ip  ${userIp}"
```

Also provided alternative way of calling request `def request = WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().currentRequest` in grails 3 the commented out line `.request` comes up unrecognised in ide (even though it works)

the `new Thread({` was still needed since even though it returned ip after getting ip it was attempting to save to a db and some other bizarre issue appeared around

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletRequest.getServletContext()Ljavax/servlet/ServletContext;
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerBase.handlePojoMethodException(PojoMessageHandlerBase.java:119)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.onMessage(PojoMessageHandlerWholeBase.java:82)
```

so the fix to getting hold of request attribute in this scenario is above

for the mock libraries you will require this in build.gradle:

```
 compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:2.5'
```

So the saga continued  - the above did not actually appear to work in my case since basically the request originated by user but when sent to websockets - the session attempting to retrieve Request (ip/session) was not actual real user.

This in the end had to be done a very different way so really steeply off the topic but when this method of attempting ip does not work the only way left is through SessionListeners:

in `src/main/groovy/{packageName}`

```
 class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
        private static List activeUsers = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())

        static Map sessions = [:].asSynchronized()

        void sessionCreated (HttpSessionEvent se) {
            sessions.put(se.session.id, se.session)
        }

        void sessionDestroyed (HttpSessionEvent se) {
            sessions.remove(se.session.id)
        }
    }
```

in `grails-app/init/Application.groovy`

```
Closure doWithSpring() {
        { ->
            websocketConfig WebSocketConfig
        }
    }
// this already exists
static void main(String[] args) {
    GrailsApp.run(Application, args)
}
```

in that same init folder:
class WebSocketConfig {

```
@Bean
public ServletContextInitializer myInitializer() {
    return new ServletContextInitializer() {
        @Override
        public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

            servletContext.addListener(SessionListener)
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now to get userIP, when the socket initially connects it sends the user's session to sockets. the socket registers that user's session within the websockets usersession details.

when attempting to get the user ip (i have registered the users ip to session.ip on the controller/page hitting the page opening sockets)

```
 def aa = SessionListener.sessions.find{it.key==sessionId}?.value
        println "aa $aa.ip"
```